# Error Trying to reinstall Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

There is 1 other post similar to this one, but its answer is kind of unclear and doesn't apply to my situation.

So, this is a bit of a long story, but it will help you understand my situation better.

First off, I am working with unity. I used Visual Studio in the past before so I didn't have the unity mod, because I did not think I would be using much unity. But now I am, I skimmed through this one youtube video and I thought I had to reinstall Visual Studio. So I made the mistake of deleting a bunch of Visual Studio files from my C: drive and deleting my recycling bin. How stupid of me. I could have just went to the Visual Studio mods website and downloaded it from there. I'm sorry for my stupidity. Anyways, when I tried reinstalling, it brought up this error:

```
Before we get started
Installation folder: 'C:Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community' could not be found.
```

I tried reinstalling Visual Studio, but it just said the same thing.

Anyone have anything to help?

Comment: If you run "Visual Studio Installer", are you able to "Repair" your installation?

Comment: No, I cannot. I believe i have to run the InstallCleanup.exe file though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating that folder and moving vs 2019 content into there